# Drupal 7: Field Permissions based on role AND relationship/referenced entity or similar

Tags: drupal, permissions, drupal-7, entity

I had previously solved this by using fields on a USER and using field permission modules to control "own" fields, but I want to switch to this setup:

Node type: "COMPANY"

Added to COMPANY are a bunch of fields:

Field 1-5:  role ADMINISTRATORS: view/update, role EDITORS: view

Field 6-10: role ADMINISTRATORS && role EDITORS: view / update

Field 11-20: only SPECIFIC USERS should VIEW/UPDATE, choosen with something like Relations or Entity Reference

Field 21-30: Same as 11-20, but now only VIEW

Since this will handle 400 COMPANY nodes and twice as many user at least, I need something automated.

A real plus if these permissions could also carry over to Views and such.

One suggestion would be to use OG, but that feels like going down the rabbit hole...

Any ideas would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation, there is no need for Relations/Entity Reference.

I would use 3 roles: Administrators, Editors, and "Specific Users". Specific Users can be given granular permissions for Fields 11-30 as needed.

If a single Role for Specific Users is too generic, you can be more granular by using multiple Roles for them, all the way down to where a Role has just a single person. That makes it very simple to administrate.

That makes it possible to just use the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module to define which Roles have permissions by field on your Content Type. If your View is referencing the Company Content Type, then as long as they can click into the Company node, they will see the `edit` tab if permissions allow.

[image: Field Permissions]

Adding in OG or other ways of dealing with this will just add unnecessary bloat to the website.

Comment: So if we have Node 44: APPLE LTD, and I only want user STEVEJOBS and user WOZ to be able to update Field 11-30, but not user BILLGATES - how exactly is this done with only Field Permissions?

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood me, I might have been unclear, but among 800-900 users I only want 2 to 8 users to be able to edit field 11-30, for each node some approx. 400 nodes.

Comment: So use the above image as an example. The majority of users can be in a role that allows View only. The 2-8 users can be in a role that allows view/edit of field 11-30. But that same role can have no permission, or view-only permission on other fields. That's the power of that module, you can mix and match.

Comment: So you want me to create a role for each of the 400 nodes? And configure permissions for that role each time?